# pandas: best way split excel to list of sheets by 'Sheet' and index?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

The problem is:

I have file with many Sheets ('Sheet1',Sheet2...) and need to create one new file with some of the Sheets (for example: 'Sheet16', 'Sheet23') or by index of Sheet for example 0(for first), 15, 22, -1 (for last).
Can help me?

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to use pandas here. Just use an Excel-related library directly.

Comment: it is part from a loop creating one excel file and i want filter and split to categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Suraj has already mentioned, you can use `xlsxwriter` to achieve the desired objective. Here's a slightly simpler and more interactive approach to your problem, using `pandas`.

To extract individual sheets from an Excel file, you can use the `ExcelFile` attribute of `pandas`. Here's how you can extract the sheets as dataframes:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
target_sheets = ['Sheet16', 'Sheet23', 'Sheet32']
```

or you can set `target_sheets` as a list of indices, say `[16, 23, 32]`

```
for sheet in target_sheets:
    if isinstance(sheet, int):
        sheet = xls.sheet_names[sheet]
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet)
    print(df)
```

This will give you the individual sheets as pandas dataframes that you can view/modify as required. If you want to create a separate Excel file combining the listed number of sheets, you can use `pd.ExcelWriter`. Here's an example:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outfile)

for sheet in target_sheets:
    if isinstance(sheet, int):
        sheet = xls.sheet_names[sheet]
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet)
    print(df)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False)
    
writer.save()
```

Feel free to tweak with the variables and make sure to include `import pandas as pd`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can skip the `ExcelFile` part and just use `pd.read_excel` with `sheet_name=None`. This will get you an easily accessible `dict` of `DataFrame`s, with the keys being the worksheet names.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you get the *data* from the workbook but likely lose formatting to be preserved in the final workbook. Pandas is too much tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

As BigBen mentioned in the comments you should use xl specific libraries.

One way would be by using [xlsxwriter](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/), a code like this might work for your use case:

```
import xlsxwriter

# Open org workbook
wb1 = xlsxwriter.Workbook('workbook.xlsx')
# Open the destination workbook
wb2 = xlsxwriter.Workbook('dest.xlsx')

# define the sheetnames that need to be copied
sheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"]
for sheet in sheets:
   ws1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
   # Create a new worksheet
   ws2 = wb2.add_worksheet(sheet)
   # Copy data
   ws2.copy_worksheet(ws1)

# Close the workbooks
wb_source.close()
wb_dest.close()
```

[openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) can also be used with a similar code structure as the above example

Comment: Statements like "you should use ..." should at least be explained/justified, if you're going to suggest the use of a different tool than the one the question was about.

Comment: @L0tad pandas is already using xlsxwriter or openpyxl under the hood. The benefit of using an Excel-related library is that you're much closer to the desired end product.

Comment: You can't read worbooks with XLSXWriter.